# Muestra la pagina en blanco

Tags: php, pdo

Se que tiene algunos errores el codigo ya que estoy empezando,por favor tengan me paciencia, hice las correciones y lo organize un poco mejor.

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db','root', '');
$login=$conexion->prepare("SELECT nombre_usuario,contrasena from usuario where nombre_usuario=':usuario'");

$login->bindParam(':usuario',$usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$login->execute();

foreach ($login as $row) {

            if($contrasena==password_verify($contrasena,$row['contrasena'])){
                echo "Usuario Correcto";
            }
            else if($row['nombre_usuario']=='' || $contrasena!=password_verify($contrasena,$row['contrasena'])) {

                echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos, por favor verificar";

            }
        }
```

En la pagina en blanco despues de ejecutar echo error_reporting(E_ALL);, sale este numero 22527.

Comment: Una página en blanco generalmente significa que ha habido un error en el servidor antes de que se escriba nada por pantalla y que tienes desactivada la salida de errores. Añade `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio de tu fichero PHP y te deberá mostrar el error que causa el problema. Cuando lo sepas, edita la pregunta para añadirlo y que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Aparte de eso, te doy la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento en general) y lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] (el código compartido no parece suficiente porque dará error por otros motivos, como por ejemplo no estar definido `$usuario`, que me imagino lo defines en otro punto que no compartes). Un saludo.

Comment: Otra cosa: si usas `prepare`, deberías añadir los valores (`$usuario`) como parámetros en lugar de concatenándolos como cadenas. Eso abre la puerta a tener problemas de seguridad graves (inyección SQL).

Comment: si ese es todo tu codigo, en caso de que el select no devuelva resultados, nunca entrará al foreach y terminara el script sin devolver nada, de ahi la pagina en blanco.

Comment: Otro fallo del código: `if($contrasena=password_verify($contrasena,$row['contrasena']))`. Estás haciendo una asignación y no una comparación, por lo que siempre se entrará en el `if` (aparte de que no es así como funciona `password_verify`) y se considerará que se ha logueado correctamente.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Aun que estoy deacuerdo en que el código tiene varias cosas a corregir, esta última que señalas no es una de ellas. `password_verify` devolverá un boleano, que será asignado a `$contrasena` que será evaluado en el if.

Comment: @Xerif tienes toda la razón. Me he confundido con la asignación.

Comment: Empieza a depurar desde el principio. Antes del `for`, haz un `var_dump($login);` para verificar si están viniendo datos en el caso en que dices que falla. Las condiciones para que entre son dos:             `$row['nombre_usuario']==''` o bien:  `$contrasena!=password_verify($contrasena,$row['contrasena']`. Si no hay un array con una clave llamada `nombre_usuario` y que además esté vacía, la cond. 1 no se cumplirá; si tampoco hay en el array una clave llamada `contrasena` la cond. 2 tampoco y por tanto no entrará en el `else`... me parece que debes mejorar un poco la lógica del programa.

Comment: No tienes que ejecutar `echo error_reporting(E_ALL)` simplemente tienes que añadir la senterncia al principio del fichero como te indica @AlvaroMontoro en su comentario. Esto hará que se muestren por pantalla los errores y avisos de la ejecución del script y resulte más sencillo depurarlo.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista, pareceria que hay un error con las comillas aquí:

```
$login=$conexion->prepare("SELECT nombre_usuario,contrasena from usuario 
where nombre_usuario=':usuario'");
```

Cuando usas bindParam() no hace falta encapsular en comillas el valor en el query, así que quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$login=$conexion->prepare("SELECT nombre_usuario,contrasena from usuario 
where nombre_usuario=:usuario");
```

Por otro lado, en lugar de `bindParam()` usaría `bindValue()`:

```
$login->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Espero que te ayude!

Comment: ¿por que bind value en vez de bind param?

Comment: `bindValue()` acepta tanto variables como valores, a diferencia de `bindParam()` que solo acepta variables. En este caso concreto `$usuario` no está declarado (supongo que hay más código del que vemos), así que podemos asumir que esta siendo pasado como variable, pero usando `bindValue()` resolvería el problema cualquiera fuese el caso.

Comment: ademas `bindValue()` asigna el valor en el momento, `bindParam()` lo hace en el `execute()` , es decir con `bindParam()` podes cambiar las variables y cada consulta sería diferente en cada `execute()`

Answer (score 0):

EN la conexion te falto **localhost**..

*$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db','root', '');*
**Asi seria:**

$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=**localhost**;dbname=db','root', '');